# Windows DNS Server - invalid domain name from outside?

Tags: windows, networking, domain-name-system

While idly reviewing event logs I saw something new (to me) this morning.

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source:   DNS
Event Category: None
Event ID:   5504
Date:       9/8/2009
Time:       8:38:09 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   MYSERVER
Description:
The DNS server encountered an invalid domain name in a packet from 72.233.33.107. The packet will be rejected. The event data contains the DNS packet.
```

I got a few mentioning that .107 address and several more for .109 as well. All within about a 5 second span of time. The event data isn't all that helpful (or is it?):

```
Data:
0000: 97 5b 80 05 00 00 00 00   [.....
0008: 00 00 00 00               ....
```

Now I'm curious... how could my *internal* AD domain server be getting packets from those ***external*** address(es)?

Comment: Did your DNS server query for an external address? In that case, it’s receiving data back as an answer to its own query.

Comment: Good point. All machines in the office point to this DNS server. It has forwarders setup (OpenDNS) for everything outside. So, in hindsight, I guess it makes sense that the events are likely in response to my server's request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this before on my own internal DNS servers. While I don't remember the exact cause, I believe that this is an incoming answer for DNS queries originating from your DNS server or answers coming from forwarders if you use forwarders. The answer has data that your server doesn't support (DNAME?).

Here's what I would do: Install a packet capture program on the DNS server, start a capture and filter for DNS, keep capturing until you see a new event in the event log, stop the capture and look for all traffic to and from the ip address in the event log, see if the packets are incoming DNS answers or incoming DNS queries.

Comment: I guess it would help if I read what others have posted before I add my two cents. I didn't notice that Nate and Chris_K said the same thing I said. Sorry.

Comment: I'd wager you're correct in that this probably did originate from my server.  

The packet capture idea is a toughie though since I've only see this error once in the past 3 years! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Decoding the data gives the answer:

```
Data:
0000: 97 5b 80 05 00 00 00 00   [.....
0008: 00 00 00 00               ....
```

Decoded is:

```
97 5b          ID  A random 16-bit query id, used to match up requests with respones
80             A bitstring
               1.......  QR (Query Response)       1: this is a response.
               .0000...  Opcode                    0: standard query
               .....0..  AA (Authorative Answer).  0: response is not authoratative.
               ......0.  TC (TrunCation)           0: response is not truncated
               .......0  RD (Recursion Desired)    0: recursion not desired
05             A bitstring
               0.......  RA (Recursion Available)
               .000....  Z  (Reserved)
               ....1001  RCODE (Response Code)     5: Refused
```

The magic is the **Response Code**:

- `0`: No error condition
- `1`: Format error - The name server was unable to interpret the query.
- `2`: Server failure - The name server was unable to process this query due to a problem with the name server
- `3`: Name Error - Meaningful only for responses from an authoritative name server, this code signifies that the domain name referenced in the query does not exist.
- `4`: Not Implemented - The name server does not support the requested kind of query
- `5`: **Refused - The name server refuses to perform the specified operation for policy reasons.**

We don't know *why* the remote DNS server refused to perform the query; but those show up in Windows Server's DNS Server event logs as informational floods.

Perhaps the foreign server was asked to perform recursion and doesn't wanna.